# Should I count the required amount of memory before allocating?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, heap-memory, dynamic-memory-allocation

Consider the following code to filter out the dash-prefixed arguments:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int    i;
    int    j;
    size_t flags_len;
    char*  flags;

    flags_len = 0;
    for (i=1; i < argc; i++) {
        if (argv[i][0] == '-') {
            flags_len++;
        }
    }

    flags = malloc(flags_len);

    j = 0;
    for (i=1; i < argc; i++) {
        if (argv[i][0] == '-') {
            flags[j++] = argv[i][1];
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Is it worth looping over all arguments twice just to count the number of flags?
Would it be viable to save the positions of the filtered elements when doing so?
Would it be worth it if we expect to allocate a lot of memory?
What option would be optimal in general? (What is 'best practice')?

- Counting before allocating (`1` call to `malloc`, large speedloss)
- Allocating buffer (`floor(n / buffersize) + 1` calls to `malloc` (or `realloc`), small speedloss)
- Allocating when needed (`n` calls to `malloc` (or `realloc`), no extra speedloss)

Comment: looping over all arguments is a really painful task for humans, but not machines, it worth doing so to avoid bad surprises.

Comment: Trying to optimize here is pointless as this is certainly not a bottleneck in your program.

Comment: for the sake of maintenance and readability, you can move the code to a new function (or macros) and call it twice

Comment: Unless you expect your program to have hundred of thousands of arguments, this is a non-issue IMO. And if you're worried about efficiency then allocating and reallocating will be less effective than your two loops with one allocation.

Comment: `flags = malloc(argc);`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: `char flags[argc];` no need for `malloc`

Comment: @MichaelWalz In this case it maybe is, but I was just wondering how to, in general, deal with variable size memory when I can count the number of elements beforehand. Imagine a `filter` function which filters out all 2 000 000 users born before 2000. Something like that.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I don't really like that solution. It's like allocating `2^16` bytes just so you can read a whole file in one go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, you didn't specify the amount of arguments you're expecting. It surely won't be a bottleneck if you're expecting arguments in amount of thousands. Remember, machine is doing this work, not you.

Allocating and reallocating is less efficient than two loops in this case. Also if you are dreading double loops, you can always allocate `flags=malloc(argc)`.

Chars are cheap. I would do  something like this,

```
flag = malloc(argc);
//your code
if(argv[i][0]=='-')
flags[j++] = argv[i][1];
```

Why? Saves me two loops, and halves the comparison. :)

Answer (score -2):

This is not tested - but something like this is more pregnant!

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int    i;
    int    j;
    int flags_len;
    char*  flags;

    flags_len = 0;
    for (i=1; i < argc; i++) {
        if (argv[i][0] == '-') {
            flags = (char*) malloc((1 + flags_len)*sizeof(char));
            flags[flags_len] = argv[i][1];
            flags_len++;
        }
    }
    free(flags);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And what happens with the old flag when you call `malloc` a second time? How do you free the previous memory?

Comment: I was thinking about using `realloc` instead, yes. I was just wondering what the best method for a general purpose program would be.